# Variable sized array of JTextFields and other widgets

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface

```
public class Creator extends JFrame {

    JLabel[] pos;
    JTextField[] monInitFi;
    JPanel panel, statusP, inputP;
    JTextField numMonsFi;
    JButton goB, initRollB;
    int numMons;

    public Creator() {
        panel = new JPanel();

        createInputP();
        panel.add(inputP);

        add(panel);
    }

    //The Input board
    public JPanel createInputP() {
        inputP = new JPanel();

        numMonsFi = new JTextField(3);
        inputP.add(numMonsFi);

        goB = new JButton("Go");
        goB.addActionListener(new goBListener());
        inputP.add(goB);

        return inputP;  
    }

    //Creates the initiative input board.
    public JPanel createStatusP() {
        statusP = new JPanel();
        monInitFi = new JTextField[numMons];

        for (int i = 0; i < numMons; i++) {
            monInitFi[i] = new JTextField(3);
            statusP.add(monInitFi[i]);
        }

        initRollB = new JButton("Roll");
        statusP.add(initRollB);

        return statusP;
    }

    //The button listener, should update numMons, and create and add the initiative panel.
    public class goBListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            numMons = Integer.parseInt(numMonsFi.getText());
            createStatusP();
            panel.add(statusP);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Creator c = new Creator();

        c.setVisible(true);
        c.setSize(1000, 600);
        c.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        c.setTitle("D&D 4e Encounter Tracker");
    }
}
```

So this is only a sample of what I'm trying to do, but I cant even get the basics to work. When I run this the `statusP(JPanel)` does not show up, and I'm not sure if it's because its not running, or because it won't work.

I've tried putting the `createStatusP()` method in the `GUI constructor` but only the `JButton` will appear as if the for loop doesn't run.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So... what is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Comment: Please make `frame.setVisible(true)` as the last line of the `main`. Firstly add components, to the container, then call `pack()` and then `setVisible()`, that way it is able to realize it's size in a much better way. Had you ever performed drawing. You donot first show your blank sheets to people, first you draw on that sheet, you paint and then show it off. Moreover, please read a bit about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Moreover, have you tried to increase the number of columns of the `JTextField` from `3` to, some larger value!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your `goBListener`'s `actionPerformed` method, you should be calling `panel.revalidate()` to force the panel to be relaid out which will trigger a repaint, after you have added the `statusP` panel.

You should also try and follow Java naming conventions, the `goBListener` should start with an uppercase, `GoBListener`, it will make it easier for others to read (but will also make it easier for you to read other peoples code)

Instead of arrays, you might consider using some of `List`, this is a personal thing, but `List` is generally more flexible.  Take a look at [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

This is because you call `createInputP()` as it's a procedure , but it's not ! it's a function it will return something that is in this case inputP panel ! so what's actually happening is overridable method call in constructor ! so the solution is add **final** keyword before createInputP() method !!

```
 // final keyword after public keyword!
public final JPanel createInputP(){ ..... }
```

And modify goBListener like below :

```
public class goBListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        numMons = Integer.parseInt(numMonsFi.getText());
        panel.revalidate(); 
        panel.add(createStatusP());
    }
}
```

Dang !! That's it !!